# how to fetch multiple values of json file in an script for autocomplete form

Tags: php, json, autocomplete

Please, I'm a beginner with php..
I would like to use an array encoded in json like this :
http://stegonia.fr/autocomplete/index2.php  (you can see result of a var_dump). 
I want to be able to see in an autocomplete form the value and label name and store the id number in my database.

I want to use this autocomplete solution :

http://stegonia.fr/autocomplete/index3.php

The javascript of this solution (index3) is :

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#speciesname').typeahead({
        source: function (query, result) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "server3.php",
                data: 'query=' + query,            
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                success: function (data) {
                    result($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return item;
                    }));
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

php code of server2 is this one :

```html
$term = trim(strip_tags($_GET['term'])); 
$a_json = array();
$a_json_row = array();
if ($data = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `taxrefv11_mini` WHERE `GROUP2_INPN` = 'oiseaux' and `NOM_VERN` LIKE '%$term%' ORDER BY `NOM_VERN`")) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
        $nomlat = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['NOM_VALIDE']));
        $nomvern = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['NOM_VERN']));
        $code = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['CD_REF']));
        $a_json_row["id"] = $code;
        $a_json_row["value"] = $nomvern.' '.$nomlat;
        $a_json_row["label"] = $nomlat.' '.$nomvern;
        array_push($a_json, $a_json_row);
    }
}
// jQuery wants JSON data

echo json_encode($a_json);
flush();
$mysqli->close();
```

Please, I don't know well javascript my question is :

If I use json file sended by server2.php, what is the right syntax of the javascript of index3 to fetch values of "id", "value" and "label" ?

Thanks
Olivier

Comment: That i see is your php is returning only the name. typing "h" returns 0:"Harle piette" 1: "h..." Must push the rows to $_a_json_row   and then push as you do now

Comment: Thanks Luis Gar. In fact, I would to use result of server2 (linked to index2) in the script of index3. But I don't know how to fetch id, value and label in this script of index3.... That is my problem.

Comment: Now you will have keys so success: function (data) {
                        return data.id;
                    }));

Comment: Thank you luis, Do you mean the new script is  `$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#speciesname').typeahead({
            source: function (query, result) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "server3.php",
     data: 'query=' + query,            
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
     success: function (data) { return data.id; }));                  
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });`   It doesn't work like this :(

Answer (score 0):

Someone helped me to solve. 
Below the solution. But there is a problem :  menu items disappear when hovering over a menu in the autocomplete form. It's discussed here :

[Why menu items disappear when hovering over a menu in autocomplete form](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49147428/9405477)

This is the entire php file. This file call a server2.php file who send json 
(http://stegonia.fr/autocomplete/server2.php)

here the entire index.12.php (http://stegonia.fr/autocomplete/index12.php)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Autocomplete with Dynamic Data Load using PHP Ajax</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
 <link href="./css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <script src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/4.0.2/bootstrap3-typeahead.js"></script>
 

</head>
<body>
 <div class="container-fluid">
  Search a species name and press enter (linotte for example) :
   <form method="post" action="index12.php" id="form">
   <input type="text" name="speciesname" id="speciesname" autocomplete="off" class="typeahead"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="speciesid" id="speciesid">
    </form>
<script>

  function html_decode(value) {
    return $('<textarea />').html(value).text()
  }

  $(document).ready(function () {
    var input = document.getElementById('speciesname');
    input.focus();

    $('#speciesname').typeahead({
      source: function (query, store) {
        if (!input.value || input.value.length < 3) {
          return [];
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: 'server2.php',
           data: 'term=' + query,
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'post',
            success: function (data) {
              var species = [];
              $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                species.push({ id: item.id, name: html_decode(item.value) });
              });
              return store(species);
            }
          }
        )
      },
      matcher: function (item) {
        return item.name ? item.name.toLowerCase()
          .indexOf(this.query.toLowerCase()) !== -1 : false;
      },
   afterSelect: function (item) {
   if (item.id) {
     $(input).val(item.name);
     $('#speciesid').val(item.id);
     $('#form').submit();
   }
   }
    })
  });
</script>
<br>
<?php if (isset($_POST['speciesid'])): ?>
  <p>The code number (id number) of the previous selected species is : <?php echo $_POST['speciesid'] ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
</body>
</html>
```