# Why menu items disappear when hovering over a menu in autocomplete form

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

Someone helped me to create a script to have an autocomplete field but I've an issue : when i leave cursor mouse outside the text field, the others matching items disappear ! Any idea to solve that ?

This file below (index12.php) call a server2.php file who send json (http://stegonia.fr/autocomplete/server2.php)

here the entire index.12.php (http://stegonia.fr/autocomplete/index12.php)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Autocomplete with Dynamic Data Load using PHP Ajax</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
 <link href="./css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <script src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/4.0.2/bootstrap3-typeahead.js"></script>
 

</head>
<body>
 <div class="container-fluid">
  Search a species name and press enter (linotte for example) :
   <form method="post" action="index12.php" id="form">
   <input type="text" name="speciesname" id="speciesname" autocomplete="off" class="typeahead"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="speciesid" id="speciesid">
    </form>
<script>

  function html_decode(value) {
    return $('<textarea />').html(value).text()
  }

  $(document).ready(function () {
    var input = document.getElementById('speciesname');
    input.focus();

    $('#speciesname').typeahead({
      source: function (query, store) {
        if (!input.value || input.value.length < 3) {
          return [];
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: 'server2.php',
           data: 'term=' + query,
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'post',
            success: function (data) {
              var species = [];
              $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                species.push({ id: item.id, name: html_decode(item.value) });
              });
              return store(species);
            }
          }
        )
      },
      matcher: function (item) {
        return item.name ? item.name.toLowerCase()
          .indexOf(this.query.toLowerCase()) !== -1 : false;
      },
   afterSelect: function (item) {
   if (item.id) {
     $(input).val(item.name);
     $('#speciesid').val(item.id);
     $('#form').submit();
   }
   }
    })
  });
</script>
<br>
<?php if (isset($_POST['speciesid'])): ?>
  <p>The code number (id number) of the previous selected species is : <?php echo $_POST['speciesid'] ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it's not working

Comment: How, I don't know why the snippet doesn't work. I made an exact copy/past of my file index12.php : http://stegonia.fr/autocomplete/index12.php

Comment: for me, i can seartch, hover over the page and menu, and select an item. but after select it shows in input and then disappear .

Comment: Where is your textarea? You said `outside textarea`, but no `textarea` at all.

Comment: Sorry for my bad translation. Text field is more appropriate !